# Communicating across channels golang

Tags: go

This program simply calculates "something" in separate goroutines and the main goroutine finally terminates after all the goroutines are finished.

The question i wanted to ask was, is the way of quitting the infinite for loop in the printChannels() an acceptable one? Or does anyone has a better approach to doing this?

```
package concurrency

import (
    "goreceipes/concurrency/syncutils"
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

// create a struct to hold the number and it's processed value
type NumberObject struct {
    number int
    value  int
}

type QuitObject struct {
    channelName string
    quitValue int
}

// Main
func main() {
    // notify the main of 4 threads in play
    syncutils.Wg.Add(4)

    // create channels for each function
    squareCh := make(chan NumberObject)
    fibCh := make(chan NumberObject)
    dblCh := make(chan NumberObject)
    quitCh := make(chan QuitObject, 3)

    // launch threads to calculate values
    go calculateSquares(squareCh, quitCh)
    go calculateFibonacci(fibCh, quitCh)
    go calculateDouble(dblCh, quitCh)

    // launch the printer thread
    go printChannels(squareCh, fibCh, dblCh, quitCh)

    // wait for threads to complete
    syncutils.Wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Terminating program.")
}

// print the output of each channel
func printChannels(sqCh <-chan NumberObject, fibCh <-chan NumberObject, dblCh <-chan NumberObject, quitCh <- chan QuitObject) {
    // let the 'main' know i'm done
    defer syncutils.Wg.Done()

    // maintains a count of how many channels are exhausted
    channelMap := make(map[string]int)

    // initialize with zero. After each goroutine is done executing, they will send a "1" into the map as a "quit signal"
    channelMap["sqCh"] = 0
    channelMap["fibCh"] = 0
    channelMap["dblCh"] = 0

    for {
        select {
        case obj := <- sqCh:
            fmt.Printf("Square of %d = \t%d\n", obj.number, obj.value)
        case obj := <- fibCh:
            fmt.Printf("Fibonacci of %d = %d\n", obj.number, obj.value)
        case obj := <- dblCh:
            fmt.Printf("Double of %d = \t%d\n", obj.number, obj.value)
        case val := <- quitCh:
            channelMap[val.channelName] = val.quitValue
            if channelMap["sqCh"] == 1 && channelMap["fibCh"] == 1 && channelMap["dblCh"] == 1{
                fmt.Println("All channels are done executing. Break the infinite loop")
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

// calculates double
func calculateDouble(dblCh chan<- NumberObject, quitCh chan <- QuitObject) {
    defer syncutils.Wg.Done()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        dblCh <- NumberObject{number: i, value: i * 2}
    }
    // send the quit signal
    quitCh <- QuitObject{"dblCh", 1}
}

// calculate fibonacci
func calculateFibonacci(fibCh chan<- NumberObject, quitCh chan <- QuitObject) {
    // let the main know I'm done
    defer syncutils.Wg.Done()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        num := float64(i)
        Phi := (1 + math.Sqrt(num)) / 2
        phi := (1 - math.Sqrt(num)) / 2
        result := (math.Pow(Phi, num) - math.Pow(phi, num)) / math.Sqrt(5)
        fibCh <- NumberObject{number: int(num), value: int(result)}
    }
    // send the quit signal
    quitCh <- QuitObject{"fibCh", 1}
}

// calculates squares
func calculateSquares(sqCh chan<- NumberObject, quitCh chan <- QuitObject) {
    // let the main know I'm done
    defer syncutils.Wg.Done()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        sqCh <- NumberObject{number: i, value: i * i}
    }
    // send the quit signal
    quitCh <- QuitObject{"sqCh", 1}
}
```

and

```
syncutils.Wg
```

is defined in a separate package so it can be used whereever required

```
package syncutils

import "sync"

var Wg sync.WaitGroup

/**
    the purpose of this file/code is to only provide a global variable Wg = WaitGroup and package it
    so it can be included wherever needed.
 */
```

Can somebody suggest a better way to terminate an infinite loop which is reading multiple channels in a different goroutine?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do without the `chan QuitObject`:

As you mention, the main issue is to quit the `printChannels` properly. Since it is listening on 3 channels, it is quite complicated to achieve.

To solve this, I recommend adding a `chan string` which would (concurrently) receive the string to print from the 3 others channels and close once they are done.

The `printChannels` becomes `printResult` (it could actually be directly written in the `main`):

```
func printResult(in <-chan string) {
    for s := range in { // this loop will end once the input channel is closed
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

To feed this channel, we need goroutines which take a result and create a string:

```
func formatResult(in <-chan NumberObject, out chan<- string, format string) {
    for n := range in { // this loop will end once the input channel is closed
        out <- fmt.Sprintf(format, n.number, n.value)
    }
}
// usage:
resultCh := make(chan string)
go formatResult(squareCh, resultCh, "Square of %d = \t%d")
go formatResult(fibCh, resultCh, "Fibonacci of %d = %d")
go formatResult(dblCh, resultCh, "Double of %d = \t%d")
// close the resultCh at the end
```

We actually just moved the issue : we now need to know when to close the `resultCh`!

The `WaitGroup` make sense here (a local variable is all that we need):

```
var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(3)
go func() {
    formatResult(squareCh, resultCh, "Square of %d = \t%d")
    wg.Done()
}()
go func() {
    formatResult(fibCh, resultCh, "Fibonacci of %d = %d")
    wg.Done()
}()
go func() {
    formatResult(dblCh, resultCh, "Double of %d = \t%d")
    wg.Done()
}()

go func() {
    // wait for threads to complete
    wg.Wait()
    resultCh <- "All channels are done executing."
    close(resultCh)
}()
```

But as-is, the `formatResult` never finish, because the input channel is never closed. So we need to modify the computation functions to close the channel after the for loop.

```
// calculates squares
func calculateSquares(sqCh chan<- NumberObject) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        sqCh <- NumberObject{number: i, value: i * i}
    }
    close(sqCh)
}
```

As a further refinement, you could change the computation functions to be just `func(int)int` and add helper functions to call them and fill the expected channel:

```
func calculate(f func(int) int, ch chan<- NumberObject) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        ch <- NumberObject{number: i, value: f(i)}
    }
    close(ch)
}
```

Final program (I integrated the `wg.Done` inside a `calculateAndFormat` to reduce verbosity, but it reduces flexibility a bit):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    resultCh := make(chan string)

    var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(3)
    // launch threads to calculate values
    go calculateAndFormat(square, resultCh, "Square of %d = \t%d", &wg)
    go calculateAndFormat(fibonacci, resultCh, "Fibonacci of %d = %d", &wg)
    go calculateAndFormat(double, resultCh, "Double of %d = \t%d", &wg)

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        resultCh <- "All channels are done executing."
        close(resultCh)
    }()

    for s := range resultCh {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }

    fmt.Println("Terminating program.")
}

func calculateAndFormat(f func(int) int, ch chan<- string, format string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf(format, i, f(i))
    }
    wg.Done()
}

// calculates double
func double(i int) int {
    return i * 2
}

// calculate fibonacci
func fibonacci(i int) int {
    num := float64(i)
    Phi := (1 + math.Sqrt(num)) / 2
    phi := (1 - math.Sqrt(num)) / 2
    result := (math.Pow(Phi, num) - math.Pow(phi, num)) / math.Sqrt(5)
    return int(result)
}

// calculates squares
func square(i int) int {
    return i * i
}
```